Interpretation of lavaan SEM growth coefficients and covariates' influence on slope
Hello and thanks in advance for advice. I am running the growth() command in lavaan. This is a follow-up to my previous post on this topic (wow, a whole year ago!).
The timepoints are at grades 3, 6, and 10. I have coded these as 0, 3, and 7 in the command to represent the years:
    i =~ 1*G3_Theta_Read + 1*G6_Theta_Read + 1*G10_Theta_Literacy
    s =~ 0*G3_Theta_Read + 3*G6_Theta_Read + 7*G10_Theta_Literacy 

Model fit is excellent:
cfi rmsea  srmr   tli 
0.987 0.026 0.010 0.974 

Question 1: This question is about interpreting the "Intercepts" for the growth (slope, ".s"). Is it accurate to say that this is the rate of growth per year in absence of the covariates? So, in this case, -.17 SD per year (standardized result), meaning -.17 * 7= -1.19 over the course of seven years? Or, is it across all seven years a total of -.17 SD?
Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .i                 0.200    0.004   45.371    0.000    0.244    0.244
   .s                -0.012    0.001   -8.638    0.000   -0.172   -0.172

Question 2: There are many covariates modeled with the intercept and slope. My second question is about interpreting the covariates' effect on the slope. Is the estimate the influence per year for seven years (i.e. for EDI_lang, this would be .033 * 7 = .231)? Or the influence across the seven years as a whole?
 Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  i ~                                                                   
    SES_cnn__2_NEW    0.076    0.003   24.806    0.000    0.093    0.100 (continous)
    Lw_r_t_rsk_Phy   -0.055    0.010   -5.417    0.000   -0.067   -0.024 (binary)
    EDI_lang          0.157    0.009   18.328    0.000    0.191    0.083 (binary)
   
  s ~                                                                   
    SES_cnn__2_NEW    0.004    0.000    9.242    0.000    0.056    0.060 (continuous)
    Lw_r_t_rsk_Phy   -0.005    0.001   -3.682    0.000   -0.075   -0.027 (binary)
    EDI_lang          0.033    0.001   27.791    0.000    0.462    0.200 (binary)

Question 3: Are Std.all only to be used for continuous covariates?
Many thanks to the Stack Exchange community for advice on this interpretation!


I have coded these as 0, 3, and 7 to represent the years ...
Is it accurate to say that this is the rate of growth per year in absence of the covariates?

It is the average change per year (across subjects)

My second question is about interpreting the covariates' effect on the slope. Is the estimate the influence per year?

An effect on the slope the time $\times$ covariate (well, moderator) interaction effect.  It is the degree to which the average rate of change differs per 1-unit increase in the covariate/moderator.

Are Std.all only to be used for continuous covariates?

I'm not sure the usual standardized solution makes a lot of sense for many growth-model parameters.  Certainly it makes sense to interpret (residual) covariance between growth factors as their (partial) correlation, but standardized slopes here are not really sensible.  There is nothing meaningful about the results in units of the growth-factors $SD$s, nor the $SD$ of each indicator.  The relevant $SD$ in a long-format analysis (multilevel model) might be the total $SD$ of the outcome.

Thank you so much, Terrence! This is incredibly helpful.
